# How to convert the output of a printf to a char?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

I'm trying to convert the output of a printf to get only an array of char after that.

```
 my_printf("%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x", gnetif.hwaddr[0],gnetif.hwaddr[1],gnetif.hwaddr[2],gnetif.hwaddr[3],gnetif.hwaddr[4],gnetif.hwaddr[5]);
```

You can see the output on putty here : [Result of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Aq6.png)

I would like to convert this to a char and then use a sendto() from a STM32 to my computer. I have a python script where I send "MAC" for example, and it would answer me "The mac address".

```
sendto(sock,/*Mycharwithmacaddress here*/,2,0,&from,fromlen);
```

How can I easily convert the output of my_printf to get only an array of char with my mac address in it ?

Comment: don't think I'm following what you're asking, but a `char` is only a byte (most likely 8 bits) .. so if you have more data to send you'll need more than a `char`.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking... Maybe you need `snprintf`.

Comment: That's... not at all how you use `snprintf()`.

Comment: @PierreP Why do you want to convert the MAC to a `char[]` string instead of just sending the MAC as-is in its original binary form? `sendto(sock, &gnetif.hwaddr, 6, 0, &from, fromlen);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you’re looking for `snprintf` which is similar to `printf` except that the output is stored in an array rather than printed. `snprintf` would be used like so:

```
snprintf(char_array, size_of_char_array, “text to print to array such as the MAC address”);
```

Here’s a minimal example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(char[]);

int main(void)
{
    char arr[100] = {0};
    snprintf(arr, 100, "%02x:%02x:...", 12, 35);
    myfunc(arr);
}

void myfunc(char arr[])
{
    puts(arr);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7BCsIwEETv@YqlIiQQQ6x4seqPlBxCYm3ApiVNRSn99rit9uQe9jBvhhmzuxuT0sZ58xjsDc59tK4V9ZWQZ@ssNO9q8IaaWodSsYIQ5yM02nk6Y0ZGAngzBh1CuZdSwQVGORUL6H0XMFFRhByQcsi2Mn@dlieEyFDNORyO7Bv49aEdhel/xNKi1t5uiP3qTekD)